# Set up htaccess so that everyone is denied except one IP, BUT it requires authenticaion

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, webserver, lamp

I want to set up .htaccess on my Apache web server such that all users are straight-up denied access except one user which is my IP. Since this IP represents my entire home network, I also want to add authentication in the case the IP is correct to ensure that only I can access that directory and no one else using my home network.

This is how my .htaccess file looks so far:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/path_to_forbiden_dir/.htpasswd
AuthName "Protected"
require valid-user
Allow from xxx.xx.xx.xxx
```

where xxx.xx.xx.xxx is my IP

This works in denying IPs outside the local network, however no authentication is shown when I try to access that directory from the IP specified. So, how can I create authentication only for the IP specified?

Comment: This works for me when I put it in a blank htaccess file. From any other IP, I get a 403, but from xxx.xx.xx.xxx, I get a 401 (need auth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, but I resolved the issue by following the instructions on
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles
I had forgotten to set up Directory override of htpasswd in apache2.conf

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Satisfy all` to your `.htaccess`